# check each element of vector against all rows of data frame

Tags: r, function, vectorization

I have a vector, for which I want to check each element against each row of a data frame. It involves a grep function, since the elements to be checked are buried in other text.

With help of [this forum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11667734/r-check-elements-of-vector-against-other-vector), I got this code:

```
    mat=data.frame(par=c('long A story','C story', 'blabla D'),val=1:3) 
    vec=c('Z','D','A')
    mat$label <- NA
    for (x in vec){
       is.match <- lapply(mat$par,function(y) grep(x, y))
       mat$label[which(is.match > 0)] <- x
    }
```

The problem is that it takes minutes to execute. Is there a way to vectorize this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've assumed you only want the first match in each case:

```
which.matches <- grep("[ZDA]", mat$par)
what.matches <- regmatches(mat$par, regexpr("[ZDA]", mat$par))

mat$label[which.matches] <- what.matches
mat

           par val label
1 long A story   1     A
2      C story   2  <NA>
3     blabla D   3     D
```

EDIT: Benchmarking

```
Unit: microseconds
           expr     min       lq  median       uq      max
1   answer(mat) 185.338 194.0925 199.073 209.1850  898.919
2 question(mat) 672.227 693.9610 708.601 725.6555 1457.046
```

EDIT 2:

As @mrdwab suggested, this can actually be used as a one-liner:

```
mat$label[grep("[ZDA]", mat$par)] <- regmatches(mat$par, regexpr("[ZDA]", mat$par))
```

Comment: I like this. It can even be put into a single line if you don't want to have too many single-use objects lying around (like `which.matches` and `what.matches`).

Comment: Huh, you're right. It's not actually necessary to add the `mat$label <- NA`. I'll add that.

Comment: Excellent! A big improvement. In reality, 'vec' contains [multiple] words, so the expression grep("[ZDA]" becomes messy. I have therefore: expr = paste(vec,collapse='|');
mat$label[grep(expr, mat$par)] = regmatches(mat$par, regexpr(expr,mat$par))

Comment: One strange thing though: I get the warning "Supplied 1296520 items to be assigned to 1296540 items of column 'mat.label' (recycled leaving remainder of 20 items)." What could this be?

Comment: Check the length of the matches and the length of the `grep` statement and see if their length is the same. If not, why not?